# How I can get table name using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have an SQL query and I want to invoke this query using EntityFramework and Linq. How can I achieve this?

I want to get table name that contain specific column name:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%CustomField%'
ORDER BY    TableName
```

Comment: You can just execute the above query via `context.Database.SqlQuery`

Comment: This question doesn't make sense... You need to read up on entity framework,

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269). You should tell what you're trying to achieve so we can judge if finding a table name is appropriate. *And* tag the EF version you're in.

Comment: Your DbContext hides the actual names of the tables and columns in your database. That makes it reusable to be used with databases with similar structures, but different identifiers. It is a design flaw if users of your DbContext need to know the names of the tables. Functionality that needs to do that ought to be functionality added to your derived DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would be searching for table like that in entity.

Msdn is full of [exemple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738694(v=vs.100).aspx).
 And the sum of it is : A parametrize query returning a `ObjectQuery<string>`.

```
using (myEntities myContext = new myEntities())
{   
    // Create a query string
    string myQuery = @"SELECT    DISTINCT t.name AS 'TableName' "+
                        "FROM        sys.columns c "+
                        "JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id "+
                        "WHERE       c.name LIKE '%@CustomField%' "+
                        "ORDER BY    TableName"; 

    // Create a query
    //If you return a primitive type you can use ObjectQuery<string>
    ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> tableQuery = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(myQuery, myContext);

    // Add parameters.
    tableQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("CustomField", "FOOBAR"));

    // Go through the Result 
    foreach (DbDataRecord rec in tableQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TableName\t [{0}]", rec[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string Query = "SELECT    DISTINCT t.name AS 'TableName' "+
                            "FROM        sys.columns c "+
                            "JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id "+
                            "WHERE       c.name LIKE '%@table%' "+
                            "ORDER BY    TableName"

    vr db = new DB();     
    string table = "YourTableName";     
    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(Query, new SqlParameter("@table", table)).ToList();
```